# filezillaでftp接続できない

Tags: ftp

macを使っています。
fillezillaでftp接続を試みると以下のようなエラーが起きます。

状態:             xx.xserver.jp のアドレスを解決中
状態:             xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xx に接続中...
状態:             接続を確立しました, ウェルカム メッセージを待っています...
状態:             TLS を初期化しています...
状態:             証明書を検証中...
状態:             TLS 接続が確立されました.
状態:             サーバは non-ASCII の文字に対応していません.
状態:             Logged in
状態:             ディレクトリ一覧を取得中...
コマンド:       PWD
レスポンス:  257 "/" is the current directory
コマンド:       TYPE I
レスポンス:  200 Type set to I
コマンド:       PASV
レスポンス:  227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx,xx,xxx,xx,xxx,xxx).
コマンド:       MLSD
エラー:        Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
エラー:        ディレクトリ一覧表示の取り出しに失敗しました
状態:             サーバから切断されました

またxサーバーのサポートデスクにはMLSDをLISTに変更するように言われましたが、
そのような設定項目が見つかりません。

Comment: バイナリモードちゃんと設定しているか、確認してください

Answer (score 1):

ファイル名に日本語（漢字やカナ文字）が含まれているのだと思います。

「サーバは non-ASCII の文字に対応していません」というのはFileZillaがASCII文字しか扱う事が出来ない事を示しています。

Macの日本語文字コードはUnicodeだと思いますから、FileZillaのサイトマネージャを開き、「文字セット」でカスタム文字コード欄に「Unicode」を入力してみてください。
Unicodeがダメなら、utf-8を試してみてください。　（私はMacを使っていないので、確認できていません）